How to change the format of tarballs when running `make dist` in autotools
I'm using GNU Autotools to build my C++ project. And I want to use make dist to create a tarball of my project.
However, the default format of tar is gnu, which supports only paths with no more than 99 characters.
But in my project, some paths of files exceed this limitation, so I want to change the format to pax or others. What can I do?

I have tried to specify the TAR variable as TAR='tar --format=pax' make dist but it failed.
After some investigations, I found that the command executed is:
$${{TAR-tar}} chof - target | eval GZIP= gzip --best -c > data.tar.gz

(where target is the target directory), where the value of $${{TAR-tar}} is the variable TAR I specified.
So when I specify that TAR='tar --format=pax', the command becomes:
tar --format=pax chof - target | eval GZIP= gzip --best -c > data.tar.gz

which is wrong, and gives me error messages as below:
tar: You must specify one of the '-Acdtrux', '--delete' or '--test-label' options

And the correct command should be:
tar chof - target --format=pax | eval GZIP= gzip --best -c > data.tar.gz

(--format=pax should be placed after -).
Then how can I change the format of tar?

Inspired by the comments below, I suddenly found that in the command tar chof - target, there is an option o in chof. This option means --old-archive acccording to the manual in tar --help, which means the tar will use the v7 format. Then the question seems to be how to remove the o option specified by autotools, i.e. change the command to tar chf - target.

One way is to create a script (e.g.) mytar, have it rearrange the args as desired and then do exec tar with the new args. Then, use TAR=mytar. Your script could even mangle the args further and invoke whatever you want (e.g. invoke paxdirectly). But, if it were me, I would shorten some paths to fit the default as I have never seen this limitation. Without looking at tar docs, is the limit for the total path or just a given subdirectory?

From https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#Formats AFAICT, there is no pax format. Only the v7 format has the 100 char limit. This doc states explicitly that gnu format supports names of unlimited length. So, I am a bit confused as to what is going on. Do you have spaces or non-ascii chars in your names?

Are you perhaps trying this on a platform where the default tar is not GNU tar?  Because, as Craig noted, the GNU tar format has no limit on file name lengths.  Nor does the legacy GNU tar format.  Nor does the POSIX format.

@JohnBollinger I considered that but OP tagged the question with linux, so???

@CraigEstey, if the OP is doing this on Linux then it is indeed likely that their tar is GNU tar, and even very old GNU tar defaults to formats that support unlimited-length names.  Nevertheless, even if we assume that the [linux] tag is in fact relevant, it's not certain that theirs is GNU tar.  Like you, I think, I'm trying to figure out where this question is coming from, given that it definitely misrepresents essential facts.

@JohnBollinger My question was largely rhetorical (for OP). If Timothy can't respond in a reasonable amount if time, l'd be inclined to close as "unable to reproduce"?

@CraigEstey, I was supposing that the OP might have encountered an actual issue with stored filename lengths.  Anyway, I think the question could be saved by changing the assertion about GNU tar to a general concern about less-capable tars.  In that case, the approach you suggested in your first comment would make a suitable answer.

Oh sorry, I suddenly found that in the command tar chof - target, there is an option o in chof. This option means --old-archive acccording to the manual in tar --help, which means the tar will use the v7 format. Then the question seems to be how to remove the o option specified by autotools.

And I am using the GNU tar 1.35 on Ubuntu


@CraigEstey, I was supposing that the OP might have encountered an actual issue with stored filename lengths. Anyway, I think the question could be saved by changing the assertion about GNU tar to a general concern about less-capable tars. In that case, the approach you suggested in your first comment would make a suitable answer.

Under linux, the default tar is gnu tar. Its default format is either gnu or posix (depending on version). So, it should not have any filename length restrictions. See: https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/tar.html#Formats

However, if the default tar is not gnu tar, one way is:

create a script (e.g.) mytar, have it rearrange the args as desired and then do exec tar with the new args.
Then, use TAR=mytar.

Your script could even mangle the args further and invoke whatever you want (e.g.):

exec pax <some_args>
exec /full/path/to/gnu/tar <some_args>
exec zip <some_args>


Other possibilities are that your filename components have spaces or some non-ascii chars that are problematic.
It's perfectly fine to place source in whatever "longish" paths you want on your development system. However, usually, a distribution package would be be better received without "excessively" long pathnames. That is, maybe install as /usr/local/myproject/{bin,lib}/...

UPDATE:

Inspired by the comments below, I suddenly found that in the command tar chof - target, there is an option o in chof. This option means --old-archive acccording to the manual in tar --help, which means the tar will use the v7 format. Then the question seems to be how to remove the o option specified by autotools, i.e. change the command to tar chf - target

As mentioned above, using a script will help. Here's a perl script [Side note: I hate *sh :-)]:
#!/usr/bin/perl
# mytar -- force autotools to _not_ use "o"

foreach my $arg (@ARGV) {
    $arg =~ s/chof/chf/;
}

exec("tar",@ARGV);


The GNU Automake 1.11.2 Manual says in Chapter 17 Changing Automake’s Behavior that:

Various features of Automake can be controlled by options. Except where noted otherwise, options can be specified in one of several ways: ... Options are applied globally to all processed Makefile files when listed in the first argument of AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE in configure.ac, and some options which require changes to the configure script can only be specified there ...
Currently understood options are:
...
tar-v7
tar-ustar
tar-pax
These three mutually exclusive options select the tar format to use when gen erating tarballs with ‘make dist’.

So we may add tar-pax options to AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE in configure.ac:
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([foreign subdir-objects tar-pax])

Then the problem can be solved, and the command in the generated Makefile changes to:
am__tar = tar --format=posix -chf - "$$tardir"

which indeed uses the pax (a.k.a. posix) format.
